# PowerPoint 2016: Text disappear when "Convert to Shape" an SVG plot

Tags: svg, microsoft-powerpoint

I am trying to "Convert to Shape" an SVG plot according to [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/work-with-svg-images-in-microsoft-office-2016-69f29d39-194a-4072-8c35-dbe5e7ea528c) tutorial *(Convert an SVG image to an Office shape)* in PowerPoint 2016.

The SVG file I am trying to edit is https://svgshare.com/i/5AL.svg (please right click the link and select "Save link as..." to download). If you insert this svg plot to PowerPoint 2016 and select it, go to **Format** and **Convert to Shape**, you'll probably see that the title and axis title disappears. How to avoid this?

Comment: Can I ask, why you are trying to edit the SVG?  What do you want to change?  PowerPoint wouldn't be my first choice. Better with a proper vector image editor such as [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) which is free.

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks for your reply. Yes, Inkscape is a good option. It’s just sometimes my users community is used to PowerPoint and I have to be make sure the SVG I generated can be edited nicely in the PowerPoint.

Comment: I understand, however you can still use the SVG in PowerPoint, after editing it in Inkscape.

Comment: @BillyKerr right. But it would be nice if people can edit it directly in PowerPoint without touch the Inkscape. After all, people have to download Inkscape and learn it and get used to it.

Comment: I have the same issue. I have graphics in CorelDRAW that I want to use in PowerPoint 2016. To animate (or otherwise manipulate) elements of those graphics, I must convert the inserted graphics in PowerPoint into Microsoft Office drawing objects. When I export from CorelDRAW to SVG, insert the SVG in PowerPoint, and then convert to an MS Office drawing object, the text is lost. I'm now exporting the graphics from CorelDRAW in enhanced metafile format (EMF). There are other issues converting SVG and EMF to MS Office drawing objects in PowerPoint, but they're beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I've submitted a corresponding idea/suggestion on the PowerPoint UserVoice website: "[Preserve text when converting SVG to MS Office drawing object](https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/288949-powerpoint-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/35075605-preserve-text-when-converting-svg-to-ms-office-dra)"

Answer (score 0):

Until Microsoft fixes this issue (or someone demonstrates that the problem is me, not PowerPoint; I would be happy with that), here's a workaround:

1. Open the SVG in a vector application such as CorelDRAW.
2. Copy the graphic to the clipboard.
3. Switch to PowerPoint.
4. **Paste Special** (keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) as "Picture (Enhanced Metafile)".

   If the Paste Special dialog doesn't offer that format (or "Picture (*Windows* Metafile)"), see if your vector app can export the graphic to a file in enhanced metafile (.emf) format or Windows metafile (.wmf) format, and then insert that file in PowerPoint (**Insert ► Pictures**).
5. As you would have done with the SVG: right-click the graphic, select **Edit Picture**, and convert it to a Microsoft Office drawing object.
6. Ungroup it (if that's what you want to do).

I'm using CorelDRAW X6. Your mileage may vary with other vector apps.

If you happen to also be using CorelDRAW, then I have a bunch of other tips for exporting SVG or enhanced metafile format for use in PowerPoint.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is stale, but I wanted to add something. I am by no means a graphic artist or even remotely knowledgable when it comes to all things Inkscape. However, I compared an SVG from Inkscape that displays correctly in powerpoint to one that does not, and the difference I found was that the disappearing paths were listed as a "use" rather than a "path" if that makes sense.

Apparently, these are clones ([How to convert <use> objects to normal paths?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/100384/how-to-convert-use-objects-to-normal-paths)). When I followed the instructions listed in that link, my SVGs started displaying their text correctly. I found it easiest to select one of the culprits, go to edit > select same > object type and then use the Alt+Shift+D shortcut to convert all clones to paths.

As it relates to this question, I can confirm that converting the SVG to a shape in Powerpoint Version 1908 Build 11929.20254 works for me. Also, I no longer lose the text after closing and reopening the file.